# Segmentation faults and lots of zombie processes from sshd user

Tags: opensuse, azure, segmentation-fault

This problem is happening on a Windows Azure Linux VM running openSUSE 12.1

In the past days I have found many unavailability problems that forced me to a reboot from management console (no even SSH access).

I have just logged in and when I try to run `su` I get a segmentation fault. `htop` shows lots and lots of zombie processes owned by `sshd` user, everyone without a command. I can't actually run anything (`nano`, `less`, `cat`, etc..., only `cd` and `ls`)

Screenshot below (I couldn't copy/paste)
[image: htop]

I can't currently do anything on my server! I surely didn't run out of memory

```
djechelon@dom:~> free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           734        616        117          0         19        290
-/+ buffers/cache:        306        427
Swap:          767          4        763
```

As you see I have plenties of RAM. I'll have to reboot the server from Azure management console. I already know (I'll confirm after reboot) that `/var/log/messages` doesn't show anything abnormal.

#### What can be causing these problems? As you see I've been up since little more than a day. What can I do to investigate and fix the problem?